# Show AdMob interstitial ad before loading composable screen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This code to show an interstitial ad works from the `onClick` event of a button inside a composable:

```
loadInterstitial(context)
showInterstitial(context)
```

But doesn't work if I call it at the beginning of the same composable, which is strange:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    loadInterstitial(context)
    showInterstitial(context)
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Interstitial loaded on composable")
}
```

It shows the log: `Interstitial loaded on composable`, which means it executed the code, but the ad doesn't show up!

Here is the code of the [MainActivity](https://github.com/rawhasan/compose-exercise-ad-network/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/adnetwork/MainActivity.kt) and [AdMob](https://github.com/rawhasan/compose-exercise-ad-network/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/adnetwork/AdMob.kt)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see a `LaunchedEffect` there. Are you calling `showInterstitialAd` in the effect? This should not be the case

Comment: Please check the link again. Pushed the updated code now.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is working as intended with Button, I guess the problem could be that the view is not loaded when you call the show method. Just try to place `LaunchedEffect` at the end of the `AdNetworkApp`, anywhere after the `AndroidView`s